# Purpose of Rendering - Do I need it?

Tags: rendering

I'm new to Blender and watching some tutorials. None seem to explain why they do certain things. One thing I don't understand is rendering. They all use this "cycle render" to make their model look nice and export a .jpeg file. Here's an example of what I'm talking about (4:42 on wards):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChPle-aiJuA

I want to create models with a texture for the purpose of getting a model and importing it into a game. I don't need any fancy picture to showcase my model. Am I missing something? Is rendering more than just dressing up the model for a nice picture?

Comment: When you just want to make game models, then you don't need offline rendering with Cylces. What you need though is a way to bake textures here and there. And this is also done with Cycles.

Comment: I did some reading. It sounds like baking is a way to calculate lighting on a 3d model.

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/learn-baking-blender

I'm not sure if I'm correct in saying this, but won't lighting be achieved by the textures and the game engine itself? My computer is reasonably fast so I think I don't need the performance boost that baking offers. 

Learning to model has been overwhelming so far. It's not that I don't intend on learning rendering, but it would help if I could put it on hold so I can focus on creating the model, texture and animations.

Comment: No. Normal maps are also baked for example. Or Cavitymaps. Or ...  - You throw lots of things together here. I feel your pain with all this new stuff. But it's unfortuantely close to impossible to explain everything here. This knowledge fills libraries ^^ . The important bit: You don't need rendering with Cycles at the moment. So just ignore. And concentrate at the game releated issues :)

Comment: @Radicool to only get the model you don't need to render, of course. You _may_ need to render it anyway _if_ you need blender to produce texturing for your game engine in order to fake normals, lighting, shadows, bumps, some time this needs a hi res version of your model (eg: to bake details into normal maps) and then apply the baked image to your low res model in the game engine...

Comment: Ok, I'll take my time learning modelling first and skip the rendering part for now. It's good to know I'm not skipping something important for my purpose. Thanks for you're help guys :)